# Window Task Scheduler Problem

Tags: windows-server-2003

I would appreciate if somebody could help me sort out a problem.

I have Window Server 2003. I am running some task with the Microsoft default scheduled tasks utility. I am using an active directory account (who is member of administrator group) to run that task.

The problem is my scheduled task stopped working so many times in a day, then I have to restart it manually.

Kindly suggest what should I do so that my scheduled task will not stop.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the event log file(s) are corrupt. I found this thread that may be helpful. Good luck!

http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-server/14754/Windows-task-scheduler-keeps-stopping